# Actualizar table con ng-repeat no funciona

Tags: angularjs, promesas

Tengo una tabla que es poblada con un `ng-repeat` que itera sobre una lista de objetos. El problema es que cuando cambia el valor de esa lista, el `ng-repeat` no refresca los datos. A la lista la tomo de una base de datos a través de un `$resource` que tengo en un servicio. Me dijeron que podría ser por un problema de caché, así que modifique el servicio para que en el método `query` del `$resource` no cachee los datos, pero sigue sin funcionar.

Les dejo el `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="missingDog">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Missing Dog</title>
        <script src="resources/dependencies/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="resources/dependencies/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="resources/dependencies/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
        <script src="resources/app/js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="resources/app/js/Services/MascotaService.js"></script>
        <script src="resources/app/js/Controllers/MainController.js"></script>
        <script src="resources/app/js/Controllers/FormController.js"></script>
        <script src="resources/app/js/Controllers/ListController.js"></script>
        <link href="resources/dependencies/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="resources/dependencies/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="resources/app/css/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
        <!-- HEADER -->
        <header class="page-header row-header">
            <div class="container-fluid row-header">
                <div class="row row-header well">
                    <!-- HEADER IMAGE -->
                    <div class="col-xs-1">
                        <img ng-src="resources/app/images/beagles.png" id="imgHeader" alt="Missing Dog" class="img-rounded img-responsive"/>
                    </div>
                    <!-- HEADER TITLE AND TEXT -->
                    <div class="col-xs-11">
                        <h1><a href="#home">Missing Dog</a></h1>
                        <p>
                            Missing Dog is a community that ensures support and charity towards stray dogs. 
                            It's a pleasure to help you find your lost pet!
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default row-header" role="navigation" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="104.97">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-2 navbar-header">
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Missing Dog</a>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="col-lg-10 nav navbar-nav"> <!-- navbar-nav -->
                            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#form">Report a Missing Dog</a></li>
                            <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#view">View the Missing Dogs</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
        <div id="mainContent" class="container-fluid" ng-controller="MainController">

                <!-- HOME -->
                <section id="home" class="row row-content">
                    <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-7 well">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <img alt="Missing Dog 2" ng-src="resources/app/images/dog-brown.jpg" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel, repellendus. 
                                Quae enim, aspernatur odit beatae illo, placeat earum impedit magni veniam. 
                                Laboriosam aperiam esse eum dolorem amet ipsum sapiente odit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
                                consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia soluta eaque velit? Quam quasi, at voluptate dicta dignissimos, 
                                quibusdam reiciendis, rem aut amet quos ut dolore blanditiis, doloremque velit mollitia! Lorem ipsum dolor 
                                sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi minus inventore corporis quasi! Nam eius quos aut dolore 
                                quibusdam quis placeat, quia, inventore dolor amet, soluta molestiae mollitia dicta praesentium. Lorem ipsum 
                                dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias et impedit, natus fuga sit earum hic reiciendis 
                                cupiditate atque dignissimos aperiam magnam esse eum, quibusdam id illum facilis optio! Eaque. 
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus veritatis natus sed ipsa, recusandae 
                                doloribus cupiditate, incidunt. Impedit nam rerum sed doloremque nisi quasi non dolores eius. Odit ad, 
                                repellat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores odit, veniam magnam quia 
                                dignissimos itaque eos reiciendis labore quasi, architecto facere amet nobis blanditiis eveniet. 
                                Earum temporibus non doloribus ex.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>

                <!-- FORM FOR REPORTING MISSING DOGS -->
                <section id="form" class="row row-content" ng-controller="FormController">
                    <div class="well col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-7">
                        <div class="col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-8">
                            <h1>Report a Missing Dog</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-11"> <!-- col-xs-offset-1  -->
                            <form class="form-horizontal" name="mascotasForm" ng-submit="guardar()">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-xs-2" for="name">Name: </label>
                                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                                        <input class="form-control" name="name" type="text" required placeholder="Name of the dog" ng-model="mascota.nombre" /> <br/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-xs-2" for="race">Race: </label>
                                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                                        <input class="form-control" name="race" type="text" required placeholder="Race of the dog" ng-model="mascota.raza" /> <br/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-xs-2" for="description">Description: </label>
                                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                                        <input class="form-control" name="description" type="text" required placeholder="A little description" ng-model="mascota.descripcion" /> <br/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-xs-2" for="lostPlace">Place where pet has lost: </label>
                                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                                        <input class="form-control" name="lostPlace" type="text" required placeholder="Place where you lost your dog" ng-model="mascota.lugar" /> <br/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-3">
                                        <input class="form-control btn-info" type="submit" value="Report" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                                        <input class="form-control btn-info" type="reset" value="Cancel" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>

                <!-- LIST OF MISSING DOGS -->
                <section id="view"  class="row row-content" ng-controller="ListController">
                    <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-7 well">
                        <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9">
                            <h1>View the list of Missing Dogs</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="race" class="control-label col-xs-11 col-xs-offset-1">Search by race: </label>
                                <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-1">
                                    <input class="form-control" name="race" type="text" required placeholder="Race of the dogs you are looking for" ng-model="query"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-10">
                                <table class="table table-striped table-responsive" ng-show="mascotas.length > 0 && mascotas != null">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Name</th>
                                            <th>Race</th>
                                            <th>Description</th>
                                            <th>Place</th>
                                            <th>¿Found?</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
        <!-- ACA ESTA EL NG-REPEAT -->  <tr ng-repeat="mascota in mascotas | filter: {raza : query}">
                                            <td>{{ mascota.nombre }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ mascota.raza }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ mascota.descripcion }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ mascota.lugar }}</td>
                                            <td><button
                                                 class="btn btn-block lost"
                                                 ng-class="{found: hover}" 
                                                 ng-mouseenter="hover = true"
                                                 ng-mouseleave="hover = false"
                                                 on-hover="Found"
                                                 on-leave="Lost"
                                                 ng-click="encontrado(mascota.id)"></button></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>

        </div>

        <!-- FOOTER -->
        <footer class="row-footer">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <p class="text-center">&copy Copyrigth 2016 Missing Dog</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

        <script src="resources/dependencies/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="resources/dependencies/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

El servicio (`MascotaService.js`):

```
(function() {

    var module = angular.module("missingDog");

    var MascotaService = function($resource) {
        return $resource("rest/mascotas/:args", {args: "@args"}, {
            'query': {
                method: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                isArray: true
            }
            });
    };

    module.factory("MascotaService", MascotaService);

}());
```

Y el controlador (`FormController.js`):

```
(function(){

    var module = angular.module("missingDog");

    var FormController = function($scope, MascotaService, $log) {

        $scope.guardar = function() {
            var mascotaJSON = angular.toJson($scope.mascota, true);

            MascotaService.save({args: mascotaJSON});

            $scope.mascota = null; //Vuelve el form al estado del modelo asociado (variable $scope.mascota en este caso)
                                   //Si $scope.mascota es null, el form toma los valores por defecto, 
                                   //de lo contrario toma los valores de la variable

            $scope.mascotas = MascotaService.query(); //Aca refresco la lista después de haber guardado un objeto nuevo.
        };

    };

    module.controller("FormController", FormController);

}());
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu código esta bien pero el problema es que mandas a hacer la query antes de que el método `save` haya terminado en el servidor. Algo como esto debe resolver tu problema.

```
MascotaService.save({args: mascotaJSON}).$promise.then(function() {
    $scope.mascotas = MascotaService.query(); 
}).catch(function() {
    // maejar error
});
```

Cuando usas `$resource` debes usar la propiedad `$promise` para obtener la promesa de la llamada Ajax asociada al método o puedes usar el método `$save` si ya has creado la instancia. Ej

```
var instancia = new MascotaService({args: mascotaJSON});
instancia.$save().then(function() {
    $scope.mascotas = MascotaService.query(); 
}).catch(function() {
    // manejar error
});
```

Usualmente cuando usas `$resource` no tienes que usar promesas pero en tu caso una llamada depende de la otra por lo que debes esperar que la primera termine.

Comment: No anduvo :S:S si refresco la página me actualiza los datos. O sea, cargo una mascota nueva, y actualizo la pagina y ahí si toma todos los datos.

Comment: Creo que debes deshabilitar toda la cache en caso que la tengas habilitada en algún lugar. Si el método no te dio error en la consola debería funcionar.

Comment: ¿Y en que otros lugares podría estar activada la caché?

Comment: @AugustoHerbel Si no tienes ninguna otra cache activada entonces me parece que el error está en el servidor. Cuando creas un nuevo objeto en la base de datos retornas la respuesta al cliente antes de que el servidor te confirme que se guardaron los datos. El código que te puse funciona ya que las promesas esperan a la respuesta del servidor para hacer la consulta de nuevo. Si la actualización fue satisfactoria deberías ver los datos en la nueva consulta.

Comment: Hay dos soluciones: primero, utilizando watchers; segundo, y no muy recomendada, es utilizar intervals.

Comment: @CésarGómez Ninguna de las dos es buena. Agregar watchers innecesarios es una mala practica y no se recomienda en angular. Usar intervalos es más mala idea aún ya que hay un método callback(`then`) que **está diseñado** para esto. La razón por la que a `$resource` se le agregaron las promesas fue para lidiar con problemas como este.

Comment: @devconcept, recuerda que si quieres hacer cambios en tiempo real, `$resource` no es capaz de hacer que la vista se renderice. Si estoy equivocado, discúlpame, pero nunca me ha funcionado.

Comment: Si lo estás. Básicamente `$resource` está diseñado para interactuar con servicios restful usando http que no tienen nada que ver con tecnologías en tiempo real como websockets. Estoy seguro que el problema se reduce a que está enviando la respuesta al cliente antes de tiempo en el servidor. Eso es mala arquitectura y tiene una solucion simple. Ni si quiera cuando usas tecnologias en tiempo real usar intervalos es buena idea ya que estas son capaces de enviar mensajes al cliente notificandole que debe actualizar la vista.

Answer (score -1):

Úsalo así:

```
MascotaService.save({args: mascotaJSON}, function() {
    $scope.mascotas = MascotaService.query(); 
}, function() {
    // captura errores
});
```

Aunque personalmente yo lo uso así para crear elementos con ngResources:

```
  $scope.mascota = new MascotaService();

  $scope.guardar = function() {

        $scope.mascota.$save({args: mascotaJSON}, function() {
             $scope.mascotas = MascotaService.query(); 
             $scope.mascota = new MascotaService(); //Esto es para limpiar el formulario en caso de que se vuelva a usar y dejarlo listo para realizar otro envió.
        }, function() {
           // captura errores
        });
  };
```